# Change html markup on element hover

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div>` full of `<ul>` elements. When i hover over one of these elements i want to make adjustments to the html markup.

my standard `<ul>` items look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="category"><img src="source" /></li>
    <li class="time days"><p>text</p></li>
    <li class="participant participant_one"><p><img src="source" />text</p></li>
    <li class="divider"><p>:</p></li>
    <li class="participant participant_two"><p><img src="source" />text</p></li>
    <li class="event_type"><p>Event</p></li>
    <li class="event_name"><p>text</p></li>
    <li class="hot"><p>945°</p></li>
    <li class="rating"><p>4.99</p></li>
    <li class="comments"><p>7.544</p></li>
    <li class="marked"></li>
</ul>
```

now on hover i want this element to look like this:

```
<ul class="expanded">
    <li class="category"><img src="img/headlines_category_icon_1.png"></li>
    <li class="time days"><p>29.05</p></li>
    <li class="icon participant_one_icon"><img src="img/user_icon_36-36_1.png"></li>
    <li class="icon participant_two_icon"><img src="img/user_icon_36-36_1.png"></li>
    <li class="headline">
        <ul>
            <li class="participant participant_one"><p>Text</p></li>
            <li><p>:</p></li>
            <li class="participant participant_two"><p>Text</p></li>
        </ul>
        <p><span>Event</span> Eventname</p>
    </li>
    <li class="actions">
        <ul class="actions_ul">
            <li class="bookmark"><a href="#">Bookmark</a></li>
            <li class="comment"><a href="#">Comment</a></li>
            <li class="share"><a href="#">Share</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i want to accomplish this using jquery and i tried following:

```
$('div.match_entries ul').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    category = $(this).children('li.category');
    time = $(this).children('li.time');
    participant_one_original = $(this).children('li.participant_one');
    participant_one_icon = $(this).children('li.participant_one img');
    participant_one = $(this).children('li.participant_one').remove('img');
    participant_two_original = $(this).children('li.participant_two');
    participant_two_icon = $(this).children('li.participant_two img');
    participant_two = $(this).children('li.participant_two').remove('img');
    divider = $(this).children('li.divider');
    event_type_original = $(this).children('li.event_type');
    event_type = $(this).children('li.event_type p').text();
    event_name_original = $(this).children('li.event_name');
    event_name = $(this).children('li.event_name p').text();
    hot = $(this).children('li.hot');
    rating = $(this).children('li.rating');
    comment = $(this).children('li.comment');
    marked = $(this).children('li.marked');

    $(this).empty();

    $(this).append($(category));
    $(this).append($(time));
    $(this).append('<li class="icon participant_one_icon'+$(participant_one_icon)+'</li>');
    $(this).append('<li class="icon participant_two_icon'+$(participant_two_icon).text()+'</li>');
    $(this).append('<li class="headline"><ul>'+$(participant_one)+'<li><p>:</p></li>'+$(participant_two)+'</ul><p><span>'+$(event_type)+'</span> '+$(event_name)+'</p></li>');

}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).empty();
    // APPEND ORIGINAL STUFF
})
```

Doesn't work quite... `$(category)` and `$(time)` are appended in the right way but the others are included as `object Object`

Any hints?

Comment: Another option: add both expanded and non-expanded versions to the markup. Hide the expanded version with display: none. Then use your Javascript to toggle the display of the hovered element.

Comment: Specify what from object, ex. could be `$($(event_type_original)).html()` or similar

Comment: The main hint is that `object Object` is what you get when you call `ToString` on an object that doesn't have an override of its own for ToString. And of course if you use an object in a string context it will call ToString implicitly. So the problem is you are treating an object (a jquery object in fact) as if it were a string when it isn't and as Alex Ball says you generally want a method or property on the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have such information to be changed on hover, maybe you should think of having directly the expanded version has an hidden one, so on hover you only have to hide the original one and then display the hidden one.

```
<ul class="original">
   <li> ... <li>
   <li> ... <li>
</ul>

<ul class="hidden">
   <li> ... <li>
   <li> ... <li>
</ul>
```

JS part

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','ul.original',function() {
   $(this).addClass('hidden')
          .next().removeClass('hidden');
}).on('mouseleave', 'ul.original', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('hidden')
          .next().addClass('hidden');
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Comment: thank you. didn't thought about that. should be the easiest way.

Comment: Ok, actually this didn't work as it should because in the moment you enter the ul.original the element your mouse is pointing loses the class 'original' which leads to "flickering".
but your approach was the right one and i found a solution: 
    $('div.match_entries ul.original').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hidden').next().removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $('div.match_entries ul.expanded').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden').prev().removeClass('hidden');
    });